# GitLab CI get last artifact

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to get the latest build artifact using `curl`. Here's what I've tried.

First, get last pipeline id:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my-token-here>" https://<project>/api/v4/projects/<project>/pipelines?per_page=1&page=1
```

Next, get job id based on pipeline id just obtained before:

```
curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my-token-here>" "https://[redacted,host]/api/v4/projects/[redacted,project]/pipelines/<pipeline-id>/jobs" | jq '.[] | select(.name == "build-assets" and .status == "success" and .artifacts_file != null) | .id'
```

Finally, get the artifacts to `build.zip` based on job id:

```
curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my-token-here>" "https://[redacted,host]/api/v4/projects/[redacted, project]/jobs/<JOB_ID>/artifacts" > build.zip
```

These steps above do work, but I have to hit three endpoints (and process the JSON response for each step).

I also read in [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts), that there's a *single* endpoint available for this. So I also tried this:

```
curl -sS --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <my-token-here>" "https://<url>/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<refs>/download?job=<job_name>"
```

but this always redirects me to the login page, saying this:

```html
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://<url>/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Is there any simpler way to do this task? Or how to use the endpoint that is described on the documentation above propeprly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Scripting artifacts download

Two methods. The second one is the solution in your use case.

#### From a Public project

```
curl -sS "https://<url>/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<refs>/download?job=<job_name>"
```

Note : I gess you can't use your personal token here, it's reserved to API usage bellow.

[Gitlab doc : downloading the latest artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts)

#### From a Private project

```
curl -L --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 123456abcdef" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/awesome-organization%2Fawesome-group%2Fowesome-project/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=publish-release"
```

Note1 : the `-l` tells curl to follow the redirection since gitlab will move you to its google storage location.
Note2 : the `%2F` value is the url-encoded replacement for the slash if your project is part or a group or subgroup in gitlab.

[Gitlab api doc : downloading the latest artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#download-the-artifacts-archive)

Comment: I suggest adding the `-f` switch, to get errors: https://superuser.com/a/657174/380720

Comment: Does the PRIVATE-TOKEN refers to personal access tokens or project access tokens?

Comment: @Kuper Personal access token with API scope

Comment: Seems like if you have manual (not successful finished) jobs, you can't download artifact

Comment: I followed the URL for private projects, and it seems now a days it is '&job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN' at the end of your URL or '--header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"'.

Comment: in the URL displayed in the Gitlab API Doc they use  "$CI_PROJECT_ID" in the URL, yet give no spec on what it is. Now I am assuming you can use the project URL encoded like you show. Only thing is it keeps returning: '{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}'. I tried every thing. Do I need to prepend my username? like "username%2Fgroup%2Fproject" or is it just "group%2fproject"? and if you open the project in the web interface there is a Project ID written under the title, can I use that one?