# Best way to group multiple Gitlab releases into one master release?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We've got multiple projects in Gitlab, i.e.:

- project1/backend
- project2/frontend-main
- project2/frontend-components

Each of the projects has its own `.gitlab-ci.yml` and releases enabled.

I'm now trying to find a way how to combine all these individual releases into a master release, e.g.

- project1/backend (v1.10)
- project2/frontend-main (v2.20)
- project2/frontend-components (v.10.10)

The above should be combined and the final result would be a master release with its own versioning (e.g. v1.1.0).

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#retrieve-job-artifacts-for-other-projects) does mention retrieving artifacts from other projects, using a private token, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56236392/6309).

That means you could have:

- a dedicated "master" project
- with its own pipeline
- and, for said pipeline, directives to retrive the latest from the other projects, and then publish then as the "master" project artifacts.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I managed to successfully grab different artifacts from different projects as part of the same pipeline. Sharing the CI file [here](https://gist.github.com/norus/332f3aec5ca4cd419d8b2afbf6f90af9) but it doesn't contain the deploy part. Hope it's useful for others nevertheless.

Comment: @norus Well done! That should be helpful indeed.